# Thunderbird Mail activation

Tags: thunderbird, mail, media-buttons

I cannot find a possibility on the desktop to activate the pre-installed Thunderbird Mail within the Ubuntu 13.04 installation

Comment: Please be more elaborate, and please say what you mean by *activating* Thunderbird.

Comment: What you mean when you say "activate" ? thunderbird is pre-installed and first you have to add an (or multiple) email account(s) and then it will be "activated". (if this is what you mean). Also check the email provider settings and see if POP3 is enabled. (it should be)

Comment: Do you want to start Thunderbird client, or what?

Answer (score 0):

The [official Mozilla support page](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux) for Thunderbird installation has multiple options. Try those, and one will work for you.